# datagridview example for sale entry form

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to make simple sale entry form,
first i want to ask invoice number and customer name, then
next details of sale entry i want add using datagridview, like:

```
sr.no---Product Name------Price---qty---total

1       Item 1            150.00  2     300.00
2       Item 2            80.00   3     240.00
```

above details i want to add using datagridview in editable rows, but with proper validation.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["l_sr"].Value = "1";
}
```

can you help for this

Answer (score 1):

**For Web Form Application**

You need to have a form with a datagridview and a model class to bind data with your gridview.Here's the full process

Take 5 textboxes, a button and a datagridview named **myGridView**.

**SalesInformation.cs**

```
public class SalesInformation
{
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

On submit(here's submitButton) button click the form will get bind with the model class,the instance will be inserted to a collection(List or any IEnumerable generic collections) and this collection will be bind with the datasource of the datagridview.

**Form1.cs**

```
    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SalesInformation> sales = new List<SalesInformation>();
        SalesInformation newSales = new SalesInformation();
        newSales.SerialNo = Convert.ToInt32(serailNoTextBox.Text);
        newSales.ProductName = productNameTextBox.Text;
        newSales.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(priceTextBox.Text);
        newSales.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityTextBox.Text);
        newSales.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(totalTextBox.Text);
        sales.Add(newSales);

        myGridView.DataSource = sales;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sachin, but i want this all in window application c# .net

Comment: Did you mean Windows Form Application?

Comment: thanks, it is working...
can you tell me the access query to get next auto number?

Comment: do you want to get the next auto incremented id in mssql? If so then you should post another thread marking this thread as answer if helps.Else new questions are hard to answer in comments.